# SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row - Not fixable with (IN) or a JOIN (I think?)

Tags: mysql, sql

All - I'm trying to do a basic (in theory) On-Time completion report.  I'd like to to list 
assigned_to_id | Percent on-time (as a percent - but this is not important now)

I figure I tell MySQL get count of all tasks and a list of all tasks marked close on a date prior to the due date and give me that number... Seems simple?

I'm a sysadmin - not a SQL Developer so excuse the grossness to follow!

I've got

```
select issues.assigned_to_id, tb1.percent from (
Select
(select count(*) from issues where issues.due_date >= date(issues.closed_on) group by           issues.assigned_to_id)/
(select count(*) from issues group by issues.assigned_to_id) as percent
from issues)
as tb1
group by tb1.percent;
```

It's been mixed up a bit with me trying to solve the multple rows issues so it may be even worse off when I started - but if I could get a list of users with their percentage that would be great!

I'd love to have use something like a "for each" but i know that doesn't exist.

Thanks!

Comment: make sure ur queries return not null and not 0 on denominator, include all selected fields in your group by clause.

Comment: provide some sample records for your tables here

Answer (score 0):

You've got a division operation, e.g `(foo) / (bar)` and both the numerator and denominator are subqueries, Since you're expecting to take those subqueries and divide their answers, they **MUST** return a **SINGLE** value each, e.g. `1 / 2`.

The error message indicates that one (or probably both) is returning a multi-value query result, so in effect you're trying to do something like `1,2,3 / 4,5,6`, which is not a valid math operation, and you end up with your error message.

Fix the subqueries so they return only a SINGLE value each.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has equivalent of cross/outer apply which match for this case

```
SELECT T.*,Data.Value FROM [Table] T OUTER APPLY
```

you can try to use that.

Answer (score 0):

What you should probably be doing is using an IF statement:

```
SELECT
  assigned_to_id,
  SUM(IF(due_date >= date(closed_on), 1, 0))/SUM(1) AS percent
FROM issues
GROUP BY assigned_to_id
ORDER BY percent DESC
```

Note here I am grouping by `assigned_to_id` and ordering by `percent`.  This allows you to calculate the percentage for each `assigned_to_id` group and order those groups by `percent`.

Answer (score 0):

if we have to exactly rewrite your query, try this.

```
select issues.assigned_to_id, ((select count(*) from issues where issues.due_date >= date(issues.closed_on) )/
(select count(*) from issues)) as perc from issues group by issues.assigned_to_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, a list of issue ids and percentage done on time.

```
select distinct issues.assigned_to_id, done_on_time.c / issue_count.c as percent
from issues
join 
  (select issues.assigned_to_id, count(*) as c 
   from issues 
   where issues.due_date >= date(issues.closed_on) 
   group by issues.assigned_to_id) as done_on_time
   on issues.assigned_to_id = done_on_time.assigned_to_id 
  (select issues.assigned_to_idm, count(*) as c
   from issues 
   group by issues.assigned_to_id) as issue_count
   on issues.assigned_to_id = issue_count.assigned_to_id
```